# How to delete local database while uninstalling the flutter windows application?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, drift

I am using the DRIFT package (formerly known as MOOR) for local database and I want to delete the database file, when uninstalling the windows application, which is saved in local machine (Windows) as db.sqlite. How can I achieve this?

[Drift package for database](https://pub.dev/packages/drift). [Drift documentation](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/). Drift code :

```
            // These imports are only needed to open the database
        import 'dart:io';

        import 'package:drift/drift.dart';
        import 'package:drift/native.dart';
        import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
        import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
        import 'package:summa_app/database/program_location/program_location_dao.dart';
        import 'package:summa_app/database/program_location/program_location_table.dart';
        import 'package:summa_app/database/programs/program_dao.dart';
        import 'package:summa_app/database/programs/program_table.dart';

        part 'summa_database.g.dart';

        @DriftDatabase(tables: [ProgramLocation, DbPrograms], daos: [ProgramLocationDao, ProgramsDao])
        class SummaDatabase extends _$SummaDatabase {
          // we tell the database where to store the data with this constructor
          SummaDatabase() : super(_openConnection());

          // you should bump this number whenever you change or add a table definition.
          // Migrations are covered later in the documentation.

          @override
          int get schemaVersion => 1;

          @override
          Future<void> close() async{
          await  _openConnection().close();
            return super.close();
          }
        }

        LazyDatabase _openConnection() {
          // the LazyDatabase util lets us find the right location for the file async.
          return LazyDatabase(() async {
            // put the database file, called db.sqlite here, into the documents folder
            // for your app.
            final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            final file = File(path.join(dbFolder.path, 'db.sqlite'));
            return NativeDatabase(file);
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here:

1. You could close the database, delete the file from the device, and then re-open it.
2. You can delete everything from all tables, without closing the database:

```
    Future<void> deleteEverything() {
      return transaction(() async {
        // you only need this if you've manually enabled foreign keys
        // await customStatement('PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF');
        for (final table in allTables) {
          await delete(table).go();`enter code here`
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou but this doesnot delete my DB file on my Machine